# Scheduling lengthy operations in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Every five minutes I check if there is something to do for the background process. It works fine, until it reaches a case where it runs for a longer time.

```
@Resource
private ManagedExecutorService executorService;

@Schedule(hour="*", minute="*/5", second="0", persistent=false)
public void sometimesALengthyOperation() {
    ...
    executorService.submit(lengthyTask);
    ...
}
```

I have handled this with ManagedExecutorService, but I'm not sure on how to handle the problem when it takes longer than five minutes and starts a second, parallel background task.

I can implement a semaphore of some kind, but I would expect this to be part of the ManagedExecutorService.
What is the "proper way" of making sure I only get one instance here?

Comment: This is a very valid question and, AFAIK, there is no "standard" solution, described in any JEE specs. In the past we have implemented it with DB locks. This means that as soon as a timer fires, it tries to acquire a row-level lock in the DB; if it succeeds, it proceeds with the execution of the business logic, otherwise it gives up, assuming that either another execution is underway or even that another node in the cluster has picked up this execution. App servers seem to do the same ([eg WildFly](https://docs.wildfly.org/17/Developer_Guide.html#EJB3_Clustered_Database_Timers)).

Comment: The answer "there is no official answer" is a perfectly good answer to me. Now I know what I need what to do. Thanks!